# in C is it possible to have a macro with conditonal break statement

Tags: c, macros, switch-statement, break

Is the following idea possible in C?

I am reaching failed. (using online c compiler to test this)

Maybe it is solvable using GOTO, but that is not desired.

Just theoretical, if there is any other solution i am missing, but the idea is to have a statemachine just be a little bit more efficient.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t shouldhavebreaked = 0;
#define BREAK_CONDITIONAL(x,y) do { if(x == y) { shouldhavebreaked = 1; break ;}  } while(0)

int main()
{
    uint8_t swh = 0;

    switch (swh)
    {

    case 0:
 
    /*if state is same, break, otherwise fall-through*/
    BREAK_CONDITIONAL(swh, 0);

    case 1:
        printf("failed \n");
        break;

    }
    printf("changed? %d \n",shouldhavebreaked);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `break` exits the `do` loop inside the macro and not the `switch`. Remove the loop in the macro.

Comment: I would suggest writing `if ( swh == 0 ) break;` rather than obfuscating the control flow with a macro

Comment: @M.M Generally, I agree, but there are cases (such as state machines) where you can create *tiny languages* by using a set of symbolic macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the `funky do{}while()` you could use the less funky `if(){} else`:

---

```
#define BREAK_CONDITIONAL(x,y) if(x == y) { shouldhavebreaked = 1; break; } else
```

---

And it is a good habit to over-parenthesize arguments in macros:

---

```
#define BREAK_CONDITIONAL(x,y) if((x)==(y)) { shouldhavebreaked=1;break;} else
```

Comment: Usage of this monster leads to            `BREAK_CONDITIONAL(a,b) c = a+b;` What language is it? Never advice this nonsense.  One of the worst macro abuses ever seen. https://godbolt.org/z/v3Kroo

Comment: Ending the macro with ```else``` is worse than not requring ```;```

Comment: i accept this answer, i do not use the else, and the program is building without the else, so i am  happy for this moment, i dont understand the side effects yet.
Bonus would be if somehow make the name stand out like a keyword, like some typedef.. so that people will see it is a break-like function

Comment: If you can avoid the `dangling else`, that's okay. (the `goto` variant could be more robust, but I don't want to evoke yet another religious war here ...)

Answer (score 1):

Those kinds of macros do not make any sense (unless you want to make code more difficult to read, understand and maintain. It will be more error-prone as well). Avoid as a plague. They look like functions and they are not.

If I hide the macro from the @wildplasser answer can you guess what this nonsense does?

```
    if(c)
    {
        BREAK_CONDITIONAL(a,b) c = a+b;
    }
```

Comment: In this case, (since there is a break inside the `if()` part) it would do exactly the same. The `dangling else` will be associated with the innermost `if`, as intended.

Comment: @wildplasser I think you do not understand.

Comment: But *why* do you expect that omitting a `;` would result in the desired behaviour? In your case it would not result in a syntax error (like in the funky `do{}while()` case).

Comment: @wildplasser For sure you do not understand. Both do not have any sense

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland have you ever read yacc/bison's output? A better question: could you do it better/cleaner? If so: do it, instead of only criticising it.

Comment: @wildplasser bison generated code is not for people. But you can read it od course if you like. Bad example

Comment: @wildplasser ***`could you do it better/cleaner?`*** Yes - I would use macros here. Simple and clean.